# What is the difference between an expression and a phrase?

Tags: phrases, expressions

I'm trying to decide what tags I should be using and realized I did not know the difference between these terms.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simply put, an **expression** is more like a saying, an idiomatic way of expressing something in less literal, less familiar terms:

> *How do you do?* is just an expression: you don't expect someone
>   to actually tell you how he is doing;
>   he should just say *how do you do?*
>   back, because it means little more
>   than "hello".

A **phrase** is just any sequence of words, usually less than a sentence:

> - rip them out
> - even the Aztec women
> - before the Spaniards
> - reloading muskets
> - because they could never have continued their rituals without
>     capturing large numbers of enemy
>     soldiers *(this one is dubious,
>     because "clause" would be a more
>     specific and thus better name)*

A great many expressions are also phrases, like *put behind bars* or *heaven forbid*.