# As a noun, "abandon" is almost always preceded by the word "reckless".

Tags: nouns, word-usage, adjectives

Feel free to correct me if you don't share the same experience, but in my own experience, usage of the word "abandon" as a noun without being apart of the phrase "reckless abandon" is extremely rare.

Is there a name for this situation where a noun is almost exclusively paired with the same adjective and is it a unique phenomenon?

Comment: This question has already been [asked and answered](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/42252/what-do-you-call-a-pair-of-words-which-would-be-meaningless-without-one-of-them). The original question is poorly worded though.

Comment: Not really an answer to the question, but "with abandon" itself is more common, and "wild abandon" is nearly as common. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wild+abandon%2Creckless+abandon%2C+with+abandon&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwild%20abandon%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Creckless%20abandon%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwith%20abandon%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇 I would agree, and the accepted answer in that question seems like the spot on answer for this one.

Comment: @JasonM [Gay abandon](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wild+abandon%2Creckless+abandon%2Cgay+abandon&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwild%20abandon%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Creckless%20abandon%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgay%20abandon%3B%2Cc0) has taken a beating of late.

Comment: Where else can one get so much relevant information in one fell swoop?

Answer (score 0):

*Carefree abandon; momentary abandon; intemperate abandon; high-spirited abandon; willful abandon; thoughtless abandon; determined abandon; studied abandon; unintentional abandon; capricious abandon; cavalier abandon; intended abandon; well-meaning abandon*; are just a few that one might possibly come across, but I am sure there are hundreds of others.

Comment: You're listing valid, but very scarce usages, with reckless abandon.

Comment: It's the _with_ that seems to be universal. Adjectives can vary, but _abandon_ seems always to be comitative.

Comment: @JohnLawler 'Carefree abandon is what that type of holiday is all about'. 'Deliberate abandon is the tactic I employ in getting my children to take responsibility' Perhaps the 'with' is still there in  essence.