# Is there a term for words that super narrow in usage? I.e. "Figment"

Tags: idioms

There are few other ones I've thought of and forgotten, but it seems there are some words in English that although seemingly very general, are actually very narrow in usage.

Like the word "figment" - it's always followed by the same 2-3 words in 99.9% of cases.

I had a list of others, but forgot them at the moment.

It's most common to discover when teaching someone else English, I've found.

Is there a list of these, and do they have a name, or are they just a random musing? Just curious.

And can you think of other examples?

Comment: It's called a "fig newton of your imagination"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do you call a pair of words which would be meaningless without one of them?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/42252/what-do-you-call-a-pair-of-words-which-would-be-meaningless-without-one-of-them)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a term for words that have a single meaning or are only used in a single context?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10614/is-there-a-term-for-words-that-have-a-single-meaning-or-are-only-used-in-a-singl)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a name for fixed expressions/idioms containing words not found elsewhere: **cranberry collocations**.

From [Fixed Expressions and Idioms in English: A Corpus-based Approach.](https://b-ok.cc/book/1205978/37adc8/?wrongHash) (Rosamund Moon; 1998):

> ***5.1.3 Cranberry Collocations** While most lexemes in the general lexicon never occur in [fixed expressions / idioms], a few never occur
> outside FEIs. Many of these are rare fossil words, or have been
> borrowed from other languages or varieties, and they include ... [Moon
> lists about 40 such words, in three separate subclasses for
> convenience of further analysis].*

I've added the nebulous slash between *fixed expressions* and *idioms* because an idiom *must* be a fixed expression: one utilising a peculiar sense of a word / a non-compositional meaning for the expression, or unusual syntax (or both).

The term 'cranberry collocation' is derived from the term 'cranberry morpheme' ('cran', appearing in no other lexeme, being the founder member of the class).

The request for a list of cranberry collocations (or any list) is off-topic.

Comment: Thanks. I've also found a similar but not identical classification of "fossil words" but that seems like it's not quite the same thing. They are words that are "obsolete except for use in a current idiom". Can't say I can exactly tell the difference. But at least they are interesting starting points to investigate.

Comment: Here's the link to ["Fixed expressions .... by Rosamund Moon" - (PDF Download)](https://b-ok.cc/dl/1205978/c3386f), if you want to add it to your answer...

Comment: Thanks, DS. I lost track of it and thought it had been paywalled. It's a fine resource.

Comment: Note that Moon distinguishes 'fossil words' from 'borrowings from other languages or varieties of language (she gives, for example, 'kibosh', though I believe it has now been verbed)', and that both occur in cranberry collocations.

Comment: I thought an idiom was a fixed expression *where the combined meaning is different from that of the literal words.*

Comment: That will include an unusual meaning for one or more words (eg '_ship_ of the desert'),  but I've added the issue of the non-compositionality of the expression to the answer. Some idioms are transparent but extra-grammatical (eg  
 'Be seeing you!' / 'Believe you me,…' / 'Needless to say' / 'Play fair' /   '[The flat] is to let' ).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Fair enough, and thanks for teaching me a new term.